# Throw new WebFaultException used in IOperationBehavior does not work

Tags: c#, wcf, http-status-code-403

I am throwing WebFaultException when I extend  Attribute, IOperationBehavior, IParameterInspector adn it does not work.

```
public class ApplicationNotSupportedAttribute : Attribute, IOperationBehavior, IParameterInspector
    {

        private readonly ApplicationNotSupportedBehaviour behaviour;

        public ApplicationNotSupportedAttribute()
        {
            Logging<string>.Error("ApplicationNotSupportedAttribute");
            behaviour = new ApplicationNotSupportedBehaviour();
        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            behaviour.AddBindingParameters(operationDescription, bindingParameters);
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientOperation clientOperation)
        {
            behaviour.ApplyClientBehavior(operationDescription, clientOperation);
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
        {
            behaviour.ApplyDispatchBehavior(operationDescription, dispatchOperation);
        }

        public void Validate(OperationDescription operationDescription)
        {
            behaviour.Validate(operationDescription);
        }

        public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
        {
            throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
        public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs,
                           object returnValue, object correlationState)
        {
        }
```

Then I have the in the service:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "myMethod", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [OperationContract]
        [ApplicationNotSupportedAttribute]
        myMethodResult myMethod(MyMethodRequest myMethodRequest);
```

After I run the code from above I get 200 Ok. If I add

```
  throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
```

in myMethod  I get 403 Forbidden. As in the bellow code:

```
public myMethodResult myMethod(MyMethodRequest myMethodRequest)
        {
            throw new WebFaultException<myObject>(myObj, HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
```

It is somehow possible to get the 403 before we actually get inside the myMethod?

Comment: Did you try any luck with IOperationInvoker? There you can do some Before and After stuff.

Comment: I've tried, but no results :|

Comment: You must use ActionFilterAttribute (not Attribute) to create your Attribute, In the method OnActionExecuting you call the throw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue in class ApplicationNotSupportedAttribute all the overwritten  methods could have been empty except BeforeCall and ApplyDispatchBehavior which should look like:

```
public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
        {
            dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(this);
        }

        public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
            throw new WebFaultException<string>("Unauthorized", HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
```

Seems I've missed the dispatchOperation.ParameterInspectors.Add(this). This solved my problem.